# Inconsistent behavior when creating arrays from two similar MySQL result sets

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop

I am attempting to create multidimensional arrays from  data in my database whereby each row would be an array. I have attempted this on two different columns with varying results which I'm not sure why.

**First Column Loop :**

```
$db_time_qry = "Select Time from Schedule";
    $db_time_res = mysqli_query($link, $db_time_qry);
    while ($row_c = mysqli_fetch_assoc($db_time_res)) {
        $db_times [] = $row_c['Time'];
    }
    print_r($db_times);
```

Which returns the following :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 06:00:00
    [1] => 06:00:00
    [2] => 06:00:00
    [3] => 06:00:00
    [4] => 06:00:00
    [5] => 06:30:00
    [6] => 06:00:00
)
```

**Second Column Loop :**

```
  $qryDay = ("Select Day from Schedule");
    $day_res_ = mysqli_query($link, $qryDay);
    while ($row_day_ = mysqli_fetch_assoc($day_res_)) {
        if (strlen($row_day_['Day'] == 3)) {
            $day_array_ [] = $row_day_['Day'];
        } else {
            $day_array_ [] = explode(',', $row_day_['Day']);
        }
    }
    print_r($day_array_);
```

Which results into this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Wed
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Tue
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Tue
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Thu
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mon
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sun
            [1] => Mon
            [2] => Tue
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Fri
        )

)
```

The second loop returns what I want but why are they returning different results whilst using the same loop? Both arrays have been declared outside of the loops like so : `$db_times = $day_array_ = [];`

Comment: Because explode returns an array and in the first one you're just adding a single value

Comment: Updated my answer with the problem that you have on the `if` clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first one you're adding values to an array

```
$array[] = value;
```

This will just add a single value to an array, so it's one-dimensional.

In the second one `explode` will return an array, so your array contains arrays and is two-dimensional.

If you want an array of arrays, you can use

```
$array[] = array(value);
```

So the first one would be

```
$db_times [] = array($row_c['Time']);
```

and the second

```
if (strlen($row_day_['Day'] == 3)) {
    $day_array_ [] = array($row_day_['Day']);
} else {
    $day_array_ [] = explode(',', $row_day_['Day']);
}
```

You also have an error in your strlen:

```
strlen($row_day_['Day'] == 3)
```

This should of course be

```
strlen($row_day_['Day']) == 3
```

if you want it to work. Since you're checking `strlen` of a boolean, it will never match and always go to the `explode`.

Comment: Yes you're correct the `strlen` syntax was invalid I fixed it and it worked as intended and didn't create a multi-dimensional Array. But with your suggested fix I have achieved what I wanted. Thank you very much for your time and explanation!